# Has anyone used a hamburger style left nav in a web application (not a website)?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, navigation, design-patterns, business-application

Has anyone used a hamburger style left navigation in a web application (not a website)? We are looking to see how you handled? If it is even popular thing to do for an application (not mobile) but would be responsive.

Comment: The question should really be *should* you use a hamburger menu in an app. I'm sure others have already, but that doesn't mean it's been successful or well received.

Answer (score 3):

As JonW said; i think you trying to ask if it's a good idea to put it in the upper left and I think not. There are ergonomic issues with placing things there (see picture below). A swipe from left to right could work however and is a common pattern (though you should still inform the user about the whereabouts of the navigation). Placing a commonly used button in an ergonomically hard area does not seem user friendly. BTW, this only counts for right-handed people.

[image]

Comment: +1 for noting it's for right-handed people. I'm left-handed and have small hands. As phones get bigger and bigger, it just becomes increasingly difficult to reach the "OK" area indicated in your diagram (but the left-handed version, of course)

Comment: Maybe because this is an application, you can have a personal setting with which you can mirror the interface. But I doubt users will find it before they are used to it.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2014/04/08/ux-designers-side-drawer-navigation-costing-half-user-engagement/?utm_content=buffer044a9&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer) showed up the day before yesterday and I think it could be to your liking.

Summary: The guys at Zeebox, a social network for TV, used a side menu with hamburger style menu in their new design around a year ago. People loved the new design, but user engagement was down. Time on site was almost halved. They changed it back and six months later (around september 2013) tried it again, but now used an AB test. Results were almost the same. Engagement was down.

Their conclusion: if most of your user engagement happens on one screen and the only navigational options are 'user settings' or 'options' (somewhat like Facebook where it's all about the newsfeed), then by all means, place those links in a side menu to keep your primary view clutter-free. But when your app has multiple views, side navigation could be costing you a great deal of your potential user engagement.